# Is it possible to overwrite a partition in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

This article: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results states that it is possible to overwrite a BigQuery table with new data however what I'd like to do is overwrite a partition (or multiple partitions). Is that possible?

I've read through tonnes of of documentation about inserting data into BigQuery (e.g. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions) and can't find any reference to overwriting partitions so I assume the answer to my question is "no", but thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 14):

You can always over-write a partitioned table in BQ using the postfix of `YYYYMMDD` in the output table name of your query, along with using `WRITE_TRUNCATE` as your write disposition (i.e. to truncate whatever is existing in that partition and write new results).

So, lets say when you run your query, and you want to overwrite a partition for date 2019-01-15 in your table named `xyz`, you just set the output destination for your query results to be `yourdataset.xyz$20190115` and specify the write disposition to be `WRITE_TRUNCATE`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That’s a neat trick. Is it documented anywhere? I’m not familiar with the phrase “write disposition” or how to specify it.

Comment: Ah, seems it’s only available via the REST API https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.html Was hoping I could use good old SQL to do the job but never mind, happy to write some Python.

Comment: Yes. You can definitely achieve this either using regular cli or using bq apis in python/java/etc. If it helped to resolve your question, please mark the answer correct :-). Thanks.

Comment: I shall. It will take me some time to verify though, watch this space.

Comment: Adding notes as I go, the following links are worth a read: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_an_empty_partitioned_table_with_a_schema_definition , https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_partitioned_tables_from_query_results, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_a_partitioned_table_when_loading_data

Comment: Any progress since 2019?

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck! This is possible through `MERGE` DML.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#pruning_partitions_when_using_a_merge_statement

My advice is to play around with it a bit.  If you can't get it working, post a new question with specific data/queries.

Comment: is this performant compared to dropping the partitions and reinsert them ?